# Replacing "H" with "Q" in R using grep

Tags: r

How can I use grep to replace the 10th alphabet `H`  in `HsdkjnsjsHlk$mH` with `Q` in R

```
s="HsdkjnsjsHlk$mH"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use either `gsub`

```
gsub("H", "Q", s)
#[1] "QsdkjnsjsQlk$mQ"
```

or with `chartr` in `base R`

```
chartr("H", "Q", s)
#[1] "QsdkjnsjsQlk$mQ"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question if you want to select it based on it being the 10th letter, and if that is always a "H", or if it is context dependent (surrounding letters).

But this would do it in this one instance:

```
gsub("sHl", "sQl", s)
```

If it is always the 10th position and you always want a Q placing there, then this is a little more dynamic:

```
gsub('^(.{9}).', '\\1Q', s)
```

If you only want to replace it when the 10th character is a H, then:

```
gsub('^(.{9})H', '\\1Q', s)
```